# Making my script UTF-8 compatible?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have quite a long script which involves chopping lots of large text files into individual words and processing them.

I lowercase everything then remove all characters except for letters and spaces with:

```
$content=preg_replace('/[^a-z\s]/', '', $content); // Remove non-letters
```

This is then exploded and each word goes into an associated array as the key with the number of occurances as the value:

```
$words=array_count_values($content);
```

I want to convert the script to be able to work with languages other than English. Is PHP going to be OK with this? Can I use UTF-8 characters as array keys? And how would I preg_replace to remove everything except letters from any language? (All numbers, punctuation and random characters still need to be removed.)

Comment: You probably don't want to remove "everything except letters" because in most languages words are not made only of letters (think accents and other diacritics).

Comment: I'd recommend you read http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/ Unfortunately, I think PHP only exposes ICU functionality for grapheme boundaries, not word boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use UTF-8 characters as keys (is there anything that can't be a key in a PHP array? :)). Your regexp might look something like:

```
/\pL+/u
```

EDIT:
  Sorry, should be:

```
/[^\pL\p{Zs}]/u
```

Comment: `is there anything that can't be a key in a PHP array?` Sure! Any non-string non-int.

Comment: The 'u' allows for the pattern to contain unicode characters, I added it just in case...

Answer (score 0):

This should work, for both your problems.

```
<?php
$string = "Héllø";

echo preg_replace('/[^a-z\s]/i', '', $string) . "\n";
echo preg_replace('/[^a-z\W\s]/ui', '', $string) . "\n";

$arr = array(
    $string => 5
);

print_r($arr);
?>
```

In the `preg_replace` the `u` flag means it's unicode safe, the `i` flag means it's case-insensitive. `\W` are all word characters.

Comment: I have already strtolower() on the text, so does that mean I can remove the i flag?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you won't be able to create an algorithm that works realiably for all languages. [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries) provides a "Default Word Boundary Specification" (which I'm not sure would be easy to implement in PHP, because the only source of character properties available in userland is PCRE; `mbstring` has this information, but it doesn't expose it), but it warns the algorithm must be tailored for specific languages:

> It is not possible to provide a uniform set of rules that resolves all issues across languages or that handles all ambiguous situations within a given language. [...]
>
> For Thai, Lao, Khmer, Myanmar, and other scripts that do not use typically use spaces between words, a good implementation should not depend on the default word boundary specification. [...]